# gsl and rb-gsl are in my gemlist so why cant the file be found within irb?

Tags: ruby, gsl

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4

Here is my gem list:

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

dicom (0.9.5)
gsl (1.15.3)
narray (0.6.0.8)
rb-gsl (1.16.0)
rmagick (2.13.2)
```

I have installed the gsl library in my home directory.

I then open irb and "require gsl" where I get the following error message:

```
require 'gsl'
LoadError: no such file to load -- gsl
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

Any ideas on why this error appears.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I discovered several gem installations on my system (.gem<TAB>). Maybe the ruby version for your gem command does not match the ruby version of your irb.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `$LOAD_PATH` in irb. This will tell you where `require` is looking for files. I'm guessing that your ruby/irb/gem environments have conflicting versions.